# React build error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

I am following along with a tutorial and when I try to build react I get an error.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)
  5 | ReactDOM.render(
> 6 |     <App />,
    |     ^
  7 |     document.getElementById('root')
  8 | );
```

I found similar issues and I tried to fix the issue based on this but to no avail.
This is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output:{
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Below I have package.json, the `"devDependencies"` are what I have found in previous solutions.

```
{
  "name": "rtsupport",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Realtime support frontend",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "develop": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node": "^10.15.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel": "^5.8.23",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

These are my initial `"devDependencies"`

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "babel": "^5.8.23",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5"
  }
```

My Node version is: v11.10.1

After trying the suggestions with:

```
rules:[
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                use: [
                    { loader: 'babel-loader' }
                  ]
            }
        ]
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This problem can be solved by setting each babel dependencies

> `>=7.8.7`

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I think your webpack test needs to include .js files if you plan to use JSX in them:

```
test: /\.(js|jsx)$/
```

Comment: I tried both ```test: /\.(js|jsx)$/``` and ```test: /\.(js|jsx)$/```  Did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

with that config you are telling to only "translate" .jsx files, and since you main file is index.js, he is not loading it, try adding this config:

with this you add js and jsx file to be resolved by your loader

```
rules: [
  {
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
]
```

my fault i thought you had a babelrc, i forgot you can create a file on same folder level as your wepback.config with ".babelrc" name and here you can specify your loading config, and tell babel to load "react" plugin

```
{
"presets": [
  "stage-0",
  "react",
  "es2015"
],
 "plugins": [
  "transform-class-properties",
  "transform-decorators-legacy",
  "transform-object-rest-spread",
  "transform-es2015-destructuring"
 ],
 "env": {
   "debug": true
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not solve the problem, same error.

Answer (score 0):

After a full day of hacking and surfing this site I found a solution.

```
module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query:
                {
                    presets:['react']
                }  
            }
        ]
    }
```

And the package.json partial:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "babel": "^5.8.23",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
```